# while(*s++=*t++) is equivalent to which expression?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

**A.** `while (*t) *s++ = *t++;`
**B.** `do { *s = *t++; } while (*s++);`
**C.** `while (*s) *s++ = *t++;`
**D.** `do { *s++ = *t++; } while (*t);`

The answer is B, why others are wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A.) vs. B.)**

B will always copy the first value before checking if the result is 0.
A will do the test first, and if the result is 0, it will stop before ever copying the first value.

---

**C.) vs. B.)**

Similar to A, C does the test first, and will never copy a value if the first value is 0.

---

**D.) vs. B.)**
After copying a value, T is incremented, then the test is done against T (the next value), instead of the previous T.

Answer (score 1):

while(*s++=*t++)

1. *t will be assigned to *s
2. *s will be checked as the condition
3. *s and *t will be incremented

A, C: The value of *s and *t would only change and incremented if the condition is fulfilled (At least 1 increment in original code).
D: Will be assigned, but *t will be checked after it has already been increased (*s will be checked before *s or *t are incremented).
B: Will correctly assign *t to *s and then check *s, increasing it afterwards.